# Data goes missing in Esri file geodatabase

Tags: arcgis-desktop, file-geodatabase, arccatalog

We currently operate a system whereby survey data is collected in the field, exported in shapefile format, edited and then appended into a file geodatabase using the *Load* function in ArcCatalog. This all works nicely.

However, when I create new features within geodatabase feature classes using ArcGIS Desktop: Editor -> Start Editing -> Create New Features, or copy and paste features between feature classes during an ArcGIS Desktop editing session, they have disappeared the next time I access the geodatabase.

I have a feeling that this is because the newly created or pasted feature classes have no attribute data.  None of the fields are required apart from FID/OID. Can anyone confirm or say otherwise?

Comment: Could you please update your question and add information about how exactly you (try to) create new features? And maybe add some sample data, and wheter fields are required or not.

Comment: Thanks Berend, I've added the information you requested, I will discuss with colleagues whether we can release any data without compromising client confidentiality.

Comment: It is rather basic thing but... are you sure you saved edits before exit the project? your newly added features, are they disappearing from the attribute table as well or just are not displaying?

Comment: Definitely being saved after editing (I double checked the first time it happened)! Features are missing from both the map space and the attribute table

Comment: Any chance you have a definition query on that layer?

Comment: I've just double checked, and there's no definition query

Comment: There's *something* missing from your question, but it maybe difficult for us to guess what it might be. Calling Esri Tech Support might be your best way to get this answered.

Comment: Is the geodatabase local or on a server/file share? What ArcGIS version? Any patches?

Comment: The files are on a server, so there's always the chance that the issue lies there.  We're currently running ArcGIS 10.5.1, I'm not aware of any patches, but I'll doucle check.  Going forward I'm going to raise this with ESRI tech support. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

There could be several factors causing this:

- Are you saving the edits before closing ArcMap?
- Are there any extent (spatial domains) applied to the feature classes in question? If you're creating new features outside the spatial domain they will not appear.
- Be sure they're not being appended to the "feature exclusion list". Go to that layer's Properties > Display > Feature Exclusion at the bottom.

[image]

Comment: Definitely saving edits - double checked. Now looked at the feature exclusion, and nothing there either.  I've checked the Domain and the limits are as follows: Max Y: 900704401074.099 Min Y: -15524400 Min X -5220400 Max X: 900714705074.099 - this should be okay for OSGB36?

Comment: well it depends where you're new features are being placed... are they within those limits?

Comment: Yes, I assume so, as the domain boundary is larger than the extent of the coordinate system